# how to use react-select list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to `react` and i want to use `react-select` in a functional component. but always getting this error:

> 'handleChange' is not defined    no-undef
>   'selectedOption' is not defined  no-undef
>   'options' is not defined no-undef

below is the code inside a file `Store.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

function Store(){

    React.useState({selectedOption: null})

    handleChange = selectedOption => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='col-md-4' >
                <Select
                    value={selectedOption}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    options={options}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Store
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

handleChange, selectedOption and options are not defined

```js
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [] //YOUR OPTIONS HERE

function Store(){
    const [selectedOption, set_selectedOption] = React.useState('')

    function handleChange(_selectedOption) {
        set_selectedOption(_selectedOption)
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='col-md-4' >
                <Select
                    value={selectedOption}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    options={options}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Store
```

You should check the difference between a [class/react Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) where you can use this (this.setState({}), this.state.XXX, this.props) for example :

```js
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

and a [react hook function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html), where you can use hooks (no this) :

```
function Welcome(props) {
  const [name, set_name] = useState('Hello');

  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! is it correct to define the options inside the `Store` method?

Comment: Yes, you can do it as a state (just like selectedOption) or a simple variable :)